# iOS - Archive Upload Failed due to error -22421

Tags: ios, applications, apple-store

I am unable to submit an iOS app to the App Store. It throws me

> Archive Upload Failed due to error -22421

I am stuck with this issue since a week now.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Apple directly?

Answer (score 2):

I've already faced this issue, and i searched lot for this issue but all answers not work

so I used Application Loader:

First, export the application Archive from Xcode's Organizer window.

Then, upload ipa file to application loader

Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader